# 90 degree turns using wheel encoders

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am currently working on a little project with an AlphaBot using a raspberry pi 3. I am trying to make the robot do a 90 degrees turn using wheel encoder state transitions, or ticks. This is my attempt:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # Importing Libraries
import time
import math

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # Choosing BCM numbering
GPIO.setwarnings(False) # Disables Warnings when setting the pins

r = 4.85 #width of robot chasis in inches
d = 8.5 #diameter of wheel in inches
C = math.pi*d #circumference of wheel in inches
slits = 20 #number of slits on wheel encoders
state_trans = 2*slits  #total # of state transitions of wheel encoders 
inpertick = C/state_trans #total inches per tick 

def pivot(degrees,turn):

    s = 0 #used to count ticks needed to pivot a certain number of degrees
    L = 0 #used for number of pulses on left encoder
    R = 0 #used for number of pulses on right encoder

    ticks = (degrees*math.pi*r)/180

    final_ticks = int(round(ticks/inpertick))

    while(s != final_ticks):
        if (turn == "left"):


            L += 1
            R -= 1
        elif (turn == "right"):
            R += 1
            L -= 1

        s += 1

    if (turn == "left"):
        GPIO.output(IN1,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(IN2,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(IN3,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(IN4,GPIO.HIGH)


    elif (turn == "right"):
        GPIO.output(IN1,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(IN2,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(IN3,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(IN4,GPIO.LOW)

    PWMA.ChangeDutyCycle(R)
    PWMB.ChangeDutyCycle(L)


IN1 = 12
IN2 = 13
IN3 = 20
IN4 = 21
ENA = 6
ENB = 26


GPIO.setup(IN1,GPIO.OUT) # Set GPIO pin 12 as an output
GPIO.setup(IN2,GPIO.OUT) # Set GPIO pin 13 as an output
GPIO.setup(IN3,GPIO.OUT) # Set GPIO pin 20 as an output
GPIO.setup(IN4,GPIO.OUT) # Set GPIO pin 21 as an output
GPIO.setup(ENA,GPIO.OUT) # Set GPIO pin 6 as an output
GPIO.setup(ENB,GPIO.OUT) # Set GPIO pin 26 as an output

PWMA = GPIO.PWM(ENA,50) # Setup ENA as PWM at 50 Hertz
PWMB = GPIO.PWM(ENB,50) # Setup ENB as PWM at 50 Hertz

PWMA.start(45)
PWMB.start(50)


pivot(90,"right")
time.sleep(2)


PWMA.stop()
PWMB.stop()
```

As you can see in the pivot() function, I count the number of ticks or state transitions that are needed to make a 90 degree turn. I try to take those number of ticks and apply it to change the duty cycle. I'm sure this is wrong but I do not know how else to take the number of ticks and translate it to what the encoders should do. Any ideas to go about this?

Comment: Does your code currently work?

Comment: It does, but it doesn't make much of a turn using the PWM I used. I'm trying to find out how to the encoder ticks to get the robot to move in those amount of ticks.

Comment: This seems like a good application for a PID controller. I would try making one that adjusts the pulse width in response to the error (actual ticks minus the expected ticks).

Answer (score 0):

I did a video on how to use wheel encoders and calculate the robot linear and angular speeds. (https://youtu.be/ktZTN5aUYPY)

If you follow the video you will see that in the project doc folder, there is a ppt file with all the formulas. (https://github.com/gusbots/mark01/tree/v3.1/doc)

Here is a snapshot of it:

[image]

where vr and vl are the angular velocities in rad/s, R is the radius of the wheel and L is the distance between the wheels.